# Error in loading checkpoint from tf.train.init_from_checkpoint with tensorflow Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to load the resnet weights from a retinanet checkpoint file into retinanet model in tf estimator

I have inspected the checkpoint file and the resnet weights are defined under resnet scope like "resnet50/batch_normalization/beta" and the model code for resnet part of retinanet is also under the same scope name. But when I try to load the checkpoint I get the following error -

```
    RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

```py
def scaffold_fn(scaffold,sess):
    tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(params['resnet_checkpoint'], {
         'resnet50/': 'resnet50/',
    })
scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(init_fn=scaffold_fn)
```

this tf.train.Scaffold object is then passed into the estimator.